# Does ServiceLoader really load providers dynamically?

Tags: java, java-9

I recently found contradictory documentation whether service loader will locate providers added to the module path after boot.

The [`ServiceLoader::reload`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html#reload--):

> ```
> public void reload​()
> ```
>
> Clear this loader's provider cache so that all providers will be reloaded.
>   After invoking this method, subsequent invocations of the iterator or stream methods will lazily locate providers (and instantiate in the case of iterator) from scratch, just as is done by a newly-created service loader.
>
> **This method is intended for use in situations in which new service providers can be installed into a running Java virtual machine.**

Which clearly indicates that the service resolution is completely dynamic.

From the other hand [`ModuleFinder::findAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/module/ModuleFinder.html#findAll--) contradicts it. 
*"A ModuleFinder is used to find modules during resolution or **service binding**."* — [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/module/ModuleFinder.html)

> ```
> Set<ModuleReference> findAll​()
> ```
>
> Returns the set of all module references that this finder can locate.
>   A ModuleFinder provides a consistent view of the modules that it locates. **If findAll is invoked several times then it will return the same (equals) result each time.** For each ModuleReference element in the returned set then it is guaranteed that find will locate the ModuleReference if invoked to find that module.

According to this quote the resolution is fixed at module layer creation which is actually expected as the whole Java Platform Module System is static by design. If new providers would've require other modules it would have to modify the existing module graph.

So my question is: Is the first quote left-over docs from [Java 8 Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html#reload--), or there might really be cases where I can add new providers dynamically?

---

Here I'm going to prove that the module finder docs is correct:

Class `com.service.Service`:

```
package com.service;

import java.util.ServiceLoader;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public interface Service {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ServiceLoader<Service> loader = ServiceLoader.load(Service.class);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.print("Attempt " + (i + 1) + ": ");
            System.out.println(loader
                            .stream()
                            .map(ServiceLoader.Provider::type)
                            .map(Object::toString)
                            .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));

            Thread.sleep(5000);
            loader.reload();
        }
    }
}
```

`module-info`:

```
module service {
    exports com.service;
    uses com.service.Service;
}
```

In a different module, class `com.provider.Provider`:

```
package com.provider;

import com.service.Service;

public class Provider implements Service {

}
```

`module-info`:

```
module provider {
    exports com.provider;
    requires service;
    provides com.service.Service with com.provider.Provider;
}
```

Here's a live GIF what happens when I first run it without the provider in the modulepath. On the second run the provider is already there, I'll try to remove it while runnning.

[image: console]

Answer (score 5):

The service provider API works on top of Java class loaders, which are not dynamic by default. The class path is determined on JVM startup and then will not be updated: the JAR you are trying to delete, is opened by JVM, and will not be released until the shutdown. If you need some different behavior, you'll need to use a custom class loader, like the ones used by JEE application servers for the deployment of webapps or the class loaders in OSGi implementations.

Comment: So what's the purpose and definition of `reload`? Btw OSGi doesn't use dynamic class loaders but plays with module layers. See [here](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2016/october/article3.php)

Comment: Since I'm not a developer of JDK, I cannot answer more precisely here about the intent of this API. My guess is that reload will work as expected when there's a change in configuration of class loaders and some classes become (un)available in the classpath. As for OSGi - everything is based on the class loaders. Module layers is just an abstraction on top of them.

Comment: Maybe a bit late: ClassLoaders like the UrlClassLoader can load additional JARs lazily. In that case, ServiceLoader could find new Providers.